# How to use ConvexOptimization on a piecewise function?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, piecewise, computational-geometry

I define a simple piecewise convex function, but `ConvexOptimization` does not take it as a valid input:

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{ -x, x < 0}, {2 x, x >= 0}}];
Plot[f[x], {x, -1, 1}]
ConvexOptimization[ f[x], {x >= -1, x <= 1}, x]


Out[]= ConvexOptimization: The function x<0 is neither convex or concave so the curvature of the objective function
 ... cannot be determined.
```

What is preventing `ConvexOptimization` from optimizing this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to with the way the function is expressed, rather than with the function itself.

An equivalent function is

```
h[x_] := Max[-x, 2 x]
Plot[h[x], {x, -1, 1}]

ConvexOptimization[h[x], {x >= -1, x <= 1}, x]
(* {x -> 0.} *)
```

Comment: Thank you!  It's a clever solution.   However, in my original application, it may not be always possible to write the function as the maximum of two functions.  I am also curious why the error message says *the function x<0 is neither convex or concave*.

Comment: A work around for a piece-wise definition would be to optimise on each piece individually, then take the minimum

Comment: Since the maximum of convex functions is necessarily convex, it should be easier for Mathematica to check such cases.  It would be interesting to see an example of a convex function with a piece-wise definition that cannot easily be written as the maximum of convex functions.

Comment: Thank you @mikado.  Your solution works in many cases.  But here is a convex function that cannot be written as maximum of two convex functions:  ```f[x_] := Piecewise[{{ (-x)^(-Log[-x]), x < 0}, {x^(-Log[x]), x >= 0}}]; 
Plot[f[x], {x, -1/5, 1/5}]```.   I hope Mathematica will be able to recognize convexity for Piecewise functions in the future.

Comment: I think your expression is equivalent to `f[x_]:=Exp[-(Log[x^2]/2)^2]` - though the Mathematica struggles to see that this is convex at `x==0`.  You should probably submit your problem to Wolfram support, as it does look strange.